# Texts, lines and length

Tags: rules, lengths

It is possible to set the width of the lines depending to text length (text aab's in MWE). Total length text aab's + line should be an equal. And I need also the "Text inside" on the same height as "Text aab". May be it is an easier way of doing this than using math mode.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}


\newcommand\tline[3]{$\overset{\text{{\normalsize #2}}}{\underset{\text{#1}}{\text{\underline{\hspace{#3}}}}}$}

\begin{document}

Text aab  \tline{(full name)}{Text inside}{0.5\linewidth - \widthof{Text aab} } 

Text aaabbb \tline{(full name)}{Text inside}{0.5\linewidth - \widthof{Text aaabbb} }

Text aaabbbccc \tline{(full name)}{Text inside}{0.5\linewidth - \widthof{Text aaabbbccc} }

\end{document}
```

[image]

An ideal expected variant is
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\signature` macro has five arguments (listed in the code); since it's not clear where to place the “text inside”, I added a parameter that tells how far from the right end is the center of this text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\signature}[5]{%
 % #1 = total width
 % #2 = padding on the right
 % #3 = text on the left
 % #4 = text above the rule
 % #5 = text below the rule
 \par\noindent
 \makebox[#1][s]{#3\ \lowrule{\fill}\makebox[0pt]{#4}\lowrule{#2}}\\*
 \makebox[#1][s]{\hphantom{#3}\ \hfill\makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize#5}\hspace{#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\lowrule}[1]{%
  \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr-\dp\strutbox+0.4pt\relax depth \dp\strutbox\hskip#1\relax
}

\begin{document}

\signature{10cm}{4cm}{Text aab}{Text inside}{(full name)}

\medskip

\signature{10cm}{4cm}{Text aaabbb}{Text inside}{(full name)}

\medskip

\signature{10cm}{4cm}{Text aaabbbccc}{Text inside}{(full name)}

\end{document}
```

[image]